# In or on the poster?

Tags: prepositions

Is this sentence correct? or should I change it?

Answer (score 2):

Need a bit more info. If you really mean a poster  (something you stick on a wall) then you would use 'on' but I suspect you mean something else.
If you mean a post (something you put online) then 'in' is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is not idiomatic. We usually speak of what is "on" a poster whereas we speak of what is "in" an article or book or table.

> On this poster, ...

is grammatical and idiomatic as is

> On the poster, ...
>
> On this, the poster, ...

would technically be grammatical if properly punctuated, but seldom idiomatic.

However, everything here is odd because posters are seldom if ever used to explain analytical methods

Comment: A simple way of avoiding the prepostion is to make the sentence active (which is usually a good idea):  "This poster explains two analytical ideas"

Comment: ***in** his poster* is actually [more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+his+poster%2Cin+his+poster&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20his%20poster%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20his%20poster%3B%2Cc0) than ***on** his poster*. Besides which, I think "container" metaphoric usages are more appropriate than "surface" metaphors when the "sub-elements" are relatively complex things (such as *explanations*), since the "literal" meaning is closer to ***within** the words* (contained in the poster).

Comment: @FF Perhaps "poster" has a different usage in the US than in the UK. "His picture was on the wanted poster" is idiomatic in the US rather than "in." Or "I saw the ad on a poster" rather than "in." I agree with your metaphoric "container" point, and it may be the meaning of "poster" that is giving me a problem: I cannot imagine someone "explaining analytic methods" in or on a poster as that word is currently used in the US.